# Display current Folder permission by a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want my script to fetch the permission details of a particular folder.

Currently, the script i have isn't much user friendly.

> icacls %1%

gives a result like this

*NT Authority\System: (I) (OI) (CI) (F)

Administrators: (I) (OI) (CI) (F)

User1: (I) (OI) (CI) (F)*

Is there a way that would enable the script to give result something like this:

**The input folder is READ-ONLY** (based on what the current permission is of that folder)

This can be possible by in power shell i suppose, but i want it in batch script or Vb script.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
@Echo off&cls
set "$Folder=%cd%"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%a in ('icacls "%$Folder%" ^| find /i "Authority"') do (
  echo %%a | find "(F)" >nul && echo FULL PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(N)" >nul && echo ZERO PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(M)" >nul && echo MODIFYING PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(RX)" >nul && echo READ^&RUN PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(R)" >nul && echo READ ONLY PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(W)" >nul && echo WRITE PERMISSION
  echo %%a | find "(D)" >nul && echo DELETE PERMISSION)
  pause
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you

But I'm facing an issue when i change the permission, there are 2 set of permissions that are getting displayed.
Image reference: http://i.imgur.com/L0n4VQX.png

This is causing the above script to return incorrect result. Anything i'm missing out on?